# Creating Virtual Disk in PowerShell / Help Understanding Error

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I am trying to setup a new Virtual Disk in Hyper-V Server 2012 r2.  Since there is no GUI, I would like to do this using PowerShell.  So far I think I have successfully created a new pool from two HDDs, but when I try to make the Virtual Disk I get an error I don’t understand.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
PS C:\Users\xxxx> Get-StoragePool

FriendlyName    OperationalStat HealthStatus    IsPrimordial    IsReadOnly
                us
------------    --------------- ------------    ------------    ----------
Primordial      OK              Healthy         True            False
StoragePool_1   OK              Healthy         False           False


PS C:\Users\xxxx> New-VirtualDisk -StoragePoolFriendlyName StoragePool_1 -FriendlyName VirtualDisk_1 -UseMaximumSize -ResiliencySettingName Simple -ProvisioningType Thin
New-VirtualDisk : Invalid Parameter
At line:1 char:1
+ New-VirtualDisk -StoragePoolFriendlyName StoragePool_1 -FriendlyName
VirtualDisk ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/...S
FT_StoragePool) [New-VirtualDisk], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 5,New-VirtualDisk
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else runs into the same thing--I was able to get things to work by manually setting the NumberOfColumns.